# Decoding QR-code using keyboard wedge in Android with barcode scanner

Tags: android, qr-code, keyboard-wedge

I need to decode a "complex" QR code with Latin character and Thai character. I need to use the keyboard wedge function of Android using the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
{

    Log.i(TAG,"dispatchKeyEvent: "+ e.getKeyCharacterMap());
    if(e.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    {
        char pressedKey = (char) e.getUnicodeChar();
        scannerCharacter += pressedKey;
    }        
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
}
```

Here is the QR code I need to decode:
(HH;อาณาจักร)

[image]

All the barcode scanner with keyboard wedge I tried did not successfully read the QR. Here is the result they get: HHò________

If you try with a common android app that uses, for example, Zxing you will be able to decode the QR code. Do you have some tips on how to decode this barcode using keyboard wedge?

Comment: This might very well be a hardware/firmware limitation in your reader. My QR Code reader on Andoird also fails, giving me `HH??????`.

Comment: Do you mean an external barcode reader or using your camera?

Comment: Using the app provided for my phone's camera.

Comment: With this app it should work https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&gl=IT